# Python Flask method definition

Tags: python, flask

When using Flask, is it compulsory to have all method definition in one file, because i'm trying to move some methods definitions in another file but 404 not found error.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to define everything in one file. This would be really bad in a bigger app :) Read [official short doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) and see suggestions there (which include Blueprints mentioned in previous answer and which is really nice way to organize big app).

Also there is a nice [sample app](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to) on how to organize and create bigger app. Could be helpful too ;)

And other methods, classes and everything which is not Flask specific is just, simple Python, so also no need to have them in one file.

Comment: Thanks, sample app is very useful

Answer (score 1):

You can move declarations into other files as long as that file has a reference to the `Flask` object you created, however if your application is getting big enough to warrant that you should perhaps begin to look into [Flask Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in Flask you can use Blueprint for doing larger application. I like the approach of creating modular application that are not too couple with each other. So you do your Blueprints that for the most part have App capabilities suchs as routing or before_request.

```
simple_page = Blueprint('simple',__name__,template_folder='templates')
@simple_page.route('/', defaults={'page': 'index'})
@simple_page.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    try:
        return render_template('pages/%s.html' % page)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

Then you register it:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(simple_page)
```

Some catch about blueprint:

- Blueprints are not app, dont expect them to behave like so.
- Blueprint can define they're own template folder, this is useful you
  can specific template and order your app by folder module of each blueprint.
- You should always remember to append a '.'  when trying to get a
  resource:

  url_for('.index') #For flask app

  url_for('.index') #For blueprints
- Blueprint are fairly new solution in Flask at the time of writing this answer are the best solution for modular application in multiple folder and share the same Flask object amos all the app.